# I need some assistance for my "online-card"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

First of all, sorry for my English. I almost finished with my first "online-card", but suddenly I have one annoying problem. I try to remove the distance between the footer and the tab-content(hungarian version is ok). I've tried many things including max-height, various of display and flex-technologies, but nothing helped. I used Bootstrap. Thank you so much for the help!

```css
.tab-content {
display: flex;
align-items: flex-start;
flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/lojaruc/15/edit?css,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `id="magyar"` has a class of `tabe-pane fade`. That's why it is not getting the class of `display: none;` when you switch to other tabs. Just need to change it to `tab-pane (+other classes)` and it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! I corrected my mistakes! I feel me really silly. I think it's high time to take some fresh air.

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
 <div id="magyar" class="tabe-pane fade ">
```

to

```
 <div id="magyar" class="tab-pane fade ">
```

There was a typo in your class name

Comment: Thank you the answers! I can't see the forest for the trees.